# whmcs upgrading 6.2.1 to 7.1.1 Error (enable query buffering )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cpanel

I can't upgrade my whmcs 
server information:

- cloudlinux
- mysql
- cpanel

**whmcs 6.2.1**
new version : 7.1.1

Error:

> Unable to complete incremental updates: Unable to import the 6.3.0
>   Alpha1 database file. Unable to import
>   /home/domain/public_html/whmcs/client/resources/sql/upgrade630alpha1.sql:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Why?